# Disconnect car battery with receiver

Tags: batteries, automotive, receiver

I have no clue what I'm doing but I want to prevent anything down the line of my car battery draining it, so I was thinking of somehow disconnecting everything down line while it is off. Pretty sure I finally kinda sorta maybe understand amps volts, ampere-hours, and how to power and use a relay switch receiver. What I know for sure I don't understand is what to actually disconnect the batter with. All I could find were things that you manually use at the battery to disconnect the negative terminal. The battery is 12 volts and outputs up to 810 amps.

Links:
[https://www.amazon.com/TalentCell-Rechargeable-12000mAh-Multi-led-indicator/dp/B01M7Z9Z1N/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=12v%2Bpower%2Bbank&qid=1587279333&sr=8-3&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M7Z9Z1N)

[https://www.amazon.com/Solidremote-12V-Universal-2-Channel-Transmitters/dp/B01JGDV8UM/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=Remote+Control+Relay+Switch+receiver&qid=1587280585&s=hi&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JGDV8UM)

https://www.autozone.com/batteries-starting-and-charging/battery/duralast-platinum-battery-35-agm-group-size-35-650-cca/377104_258029_25698

Comment: this looks like an XY problem ... you are asking for help with what you consider to be a solution to an unspecified problem, even if your solution may be misguided .... what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? ... why would your battery be getting drained?

Comment: It's also a perfect example of why the old ["too broad"](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7167/needs-more-focus-significantly-different-from-former-too-broad-close-reason) closing category was much more useful than the current "needs more focus".

Comment: I mean I'm asking about the switch thing because I'm pretty sure trying to figure out what exactly is draining the battery would be harder than just not letting anything drain it. Of course I could be wrong, but as of rn my goal is still to stop power going to anything that drains the car when turned off.

Comment: I think I've got a better understanding of what I need to do now that I'm pretty sure I don't need to worry about 800 amps.

Comment: @Tentai ... and you'd be wrong! Building a switch that withstands the high currents of a starter motor isn't easy, or cheap (see KyleB's answer). So, back to square one :( As jsotola said, yep, you're asking about a "solution" that's not even close to a solution to your actual problem :(

Comment: What is causing your battery to drain faster than normal? Alarm circuit? Standard. Clock? Standard. Cars with good batteries can be left a week or more without issue. Either you have a different issue or a knackered battery.

Comment: Just one question: How do you plan to power your receiver?

Comment: with the rechargeable battery I linked and a solar panel. @MarcusMüller As I said I'm pretty sure I don't have to mess with high amps because that only goes to starter so I can just cut off the things that drain the battery when the car is off.

Comment: aha. But honestly, the things that drain the battery in your car shouldn't be draining your battery notably, at all! You're solving the wrong problem, still. My bet is that it's what it is for 99.5% of car owners when their battery dies after a few days to weeks sitting unused: the battery is degraded and has high self-discharge, and you could completely remove it from the car and put it on a shelf, unconnected to anything, and it would still be empty after a while.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah I'm going to figure out what is draining and replace it, as that seems to be the popular advice. How do I close this question? Do I just delete it

Comment: as said, there's probably nothing *draining* it. it's self-discharging. It's "draining itself", if you will. There's probably nothing to replace but the battery.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's possible but that last battery had this problem and it was replaced with current one and still has problem

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'll do that if I don't find anything discharging it though

Comment: Why don't you just use the solar panel to keep the main battery topped up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a waste of time and effort and probably introduces a reliability safety risk.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUIClI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. General overview schematic of automotive power distribution.*

The starter solenoid, ignition circuits (spark plugs, etc.) and auxiliaries (lights, indicators, interior fan, etc.) are already controlled by the ignition keyswitch so there is no need for additional isolation. The always on power feeds things like the door lights and radio (which may need a password on power-up) and these are really the only leakage paths that you need to be worried about.

> All I could find were things that you manually use at the battery to disconnect the negative terminal.

Isolating the battery negative is the recommended practice for maintenance because it eliminates the chassis return path. Consider what happens if you use a spanner to disconnect the positive terminal while chassis is still connected to negative: if the spanner touches any chassis metalwork while undoing the terminal a short-circuit will occur. That can't happen while disconnecting the negative terminal and once done it can't happen with the positive terminal.

If you were to proceed with your scheme you would only need to cut the auxiliaries positive feed.

> The battery is 12 volts and outputs up to 810 amps.

There's the problem. You need a huge solenoid and you've got to keep it on all the time so it will run hot. You've also got to be very confident that it won't fail while running.

I suspect you are trying to solve an imaginary problem and can't think why you would want a solution that uses a remote control which introduces another level of complexity and potential random failure.

Comment: Would you suggest just using a switch on the passive components then so that the amount of current required to start the car never runs through my solution? The battery is only a month old so I'm not sure what the problem could be if it being drained isn't the issue (it was the same with the previous battery, but that one did have some corrosion). What happens is if I don't start the car for about 3ish days the battery will be completely dead; the fob, interior lights, nothing even lights up. Quite honestly I'm not even 100% sure what the thing I'm thinking of is called

Comment: The remote is just so that I can still use the key fob. I'm pretty sure the receiver can be the same frequency as the one in my car, so I can just press the unlock button twice to turn on power and unlock the car.

Comment: I was thinking of using a 12 volt power bank that would be powered by a solar charger, but if that is not practical I'm open to changing something. I would be ok with just using a physical switch if messing with receivers is too complicated.

Comment: (1) The right way to proceed is to measure the current leaving the battery and pull each fuse until the current drops to zero. Then figure out what's on that fuse that's constantly drawing power. (2) The remote control is not a simple "frequency"; the frequency is modulated with a unique code which is decoded by the receiver. You are unlikely to be able to figure this out. (3) Note that your proposed circuit will disable the remote receiver so you won't be able to unlock the car by remote control anymore.

Comment: Ok thanks, what would be my next step if I figure out what is drawing current? Would I just need to completely disconnect it or should I just wait and find more specific information

Comment: It depends on what the problem is and whether or not the circuit is required. Repair would be the normal procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You want to disconnect the battery from the entire car, starter motor included?
You'll need a relay that could withstand 800A in that case.

Like you, the mechanical cut-outs I've seen are like big screws - Lots of surface area so they can pass lots of current.  Hard to get that much surface area in a relay.

Comment: I mean, the starter relay handles it.

Comment: True.   However the starter relay is not made to stay energized. Possibly would get quite hot and meltdown.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned whether you are using this car battery in your car (as its main battery) or outside of the car.
If outside of the car, you only have to worry about the maximum current being used, not about the maximum current capability of the battery.
If inside the car, you can greatly reduce your control circuit current handling capability by leaving the cranking lead connected (as it is not using power until starting the car anyway); that is your largest load in the car and is best left alone.
You could also measure other wires (if there are more than 2) for any current while the car is off, but then you will leave the car's computer without power, and you could run into a few problems like not being able to start or unlock your car.

Either way, for very large currents (over 20-30 amps, and especially over 50-100 amps) you need to use a larger and more powerful relay with a significantly more power-hungry solenoid OR you can use a few MOSFETS of a very low on resistance (Rds ON) in parallel, and these MOSFETS would require practically no power while being turned on or off, only a brief spike of current during the turn on and turn off.

In order to help you more effectively, you need to give us more information, photos of your setup, drawing of your intended wiring (diagram), etc.
If we know more about the intended use and the way you want to wire everything up, we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry yes I am using it in my car. My only plan really was to see what needs to be wired up and google how it goes together. To be clear I'm 19 and have zero experience beyond highschool in this, but my dad does have the tools to do any wiring I need to do. I clarified more in another comment.

Comment: OK, I have checked your other answers/comments and I see that you have a high battery drain problem. The first thing you need to do is figure out what is draining your battery so much, because a new one should last at the very least a week or two, if not even a month. You likely have a faulty device, switch, wire somewhere in the car, so find it and replace it. It might take some time but it's worth it. Ask someone nearby who knows more about the car electrical installations.

Comment: If you are driving the car for very short amounts of time (less than 10 minutes at a time), chances are your battery doesn't get a chance to recharge between the ignitions/crankings which use between 100 and 400 amps. In this case, you should do any or all of the 3: 1.) Leave the engine on a little longer so that it runs at least 10 minutes after the ignition. 2.) Connect your battery to some small charger whenever you can (at home) to keep it replenished. 3.) Place a 20-30W solar panel somewhere in or on your car to keep charging the battery during the day. It should have some charge control.

Comment: Thanks, it seems my best course of action from everything is to just do that and figure out why it is draining.